# Count the percentage of the number of the current iteration in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I am trying to build up a script that gets the current percentage of the iteration of a loop.

I have :

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    $total = 100;
    foreach($key as value) {
      $counter = $counter + 1;
      //looping here
      $percentage = $counter/total;
    }
```

In my case outputs within the loop for 5 iterations

```
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
```

And I need it to output

```
20
40
60
80
100
```

To do something like a current percentage completion.

More random exmaples
For 10 loops should be

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

For 100 loops

```
1
2
.
.
100
```

For 6 loops

```
16.6
//brain damaged
```

Sorry for the noob math php question but I am in a fog today like no days. Thank you and it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have to get the total amount of iterations. [count()](http://php.net/count) helps in this case.

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    $total = count($yourArray);

    // ...
      // inside the loop
      $counter++;
      $percentage = $counter/$total;
```

[Live example](https://eval.in/151296)

Converting `0.xx` to `x %` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate percentage, you take the current and divide it by the total, then multiply that value by 100, then round it off. I also take the floor value so that 99.7% doesn't round up to 100 since it's not truly complete yet.

```
    for($i=1;$i<=count($yourArray);$i++) {
      $percentage = floor(round( (($i / total) * 100), 1 ));
    }
```

Comment: Agreed, but OP wanted to explicitly set $total. It would handle as many iterations as necessary if he did a count() on his $key array to set $total instead.

Comment: "I am trying to build up a script that gets the current percentage of the iteration of a loop."

Comment: Touche. Not only edited to be correct then, but is a better way of writing the statement than other answers now :p

Answer (score 0):

Store the total length of the array in a variable and use that to calculate the percentage. Watch that you prefix your variables with `$`. Also, you might want to name your variables more appropriately—an array isn't a key.

```
$counter = 0;
$length  = count($array);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $counter++;
    $percentage = $counter / $length;
}
```

Comment: If you want to have the numbers in a format like `20%` instead of `0.2`, then you can just multiply `$percentage` by 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly what are you asking in this way

```
$counter = 0;
$length  = count($array);

foreach ($array as $value) {

$counter=$counter+1;
for ($stepvvx = 10; $stepvvx <= 100; $stepvvx=$stepvvx+10)
    {
if ($counter==intval(($length*$stepvvx)/100)){
    echo "<br>$stepvvx %";
}

# do your task here

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to do ($total/$iterations) * $counter  like this code:

```
 $counter = 0;
 $total = 100;
 $iterations = count($key);

 foreach($key as value) {
      $counter++;
      $percentage = (($total/$iterations) * $counter)/100;
 }
```

Comment: this outputs only 0. For example for 3 loops, outputs 0, 3 times.

Comment: because I did not insert the $counter++ in here. You need to increment $counter.